# Fetch products by category id using pivot table

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

I have a function where I am passing the category id and based on that I want to fetch all the products .

Here is a structure of my db

Category db:

```
category_name
```

Product db:

```
product_name;
```

category_product:

```
category_id;
product_id;
```

Below are the relations between them

In Product :

```
public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
```

In Category:

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }
```

I have tested multiple queries but nothing worked for my case .

Comment: whats the name of  category and product table in database.also can you show how you executing query

Comment: Its basically just a name of category and in products it is product name .

Comment: I am exectung the query in this way 
$categoryId = 1;

$products = Product::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use($categoryId) {
    $query->where('id', $categoryId);
})->get();

Comment: can you show table names in database for both tables

Comment: products , categories and for pivot table category_product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in two different ways

Indirect way wich verifies that the category exists (2 queries)

```
$category = Category::with('products')->findOrFail($categoryId);
// you can also do without the with(); only one id, so no benefit for the eager load
// $category = Category::findOrFail($categoryId);
$products = $category->products;
```

Direct way, wich will return an empty collection if the category doesnt exist (but no message) (1 query)

```
$products = Product::whereHas('categories', function($qbCategory) use($categoryId) {
    $qbCategory->where('id',$categoryId);
})->get();
```

Comment: It Worked for my case actually I will surely have category before fetching the products so the first one will be useful for me but yeah second one is also good approach to avoid errors .

Comment: @SyedKhizer Actually, i usualy use the first one to avoid errors. it's a good thing to know if something is wrong in the inputs.